# How to use Netbeans to to export maven project as runnable jar?

Tags: maven, netbeans, jar, runnable

I have used Netbeans to package my projects using ant as runnable jars, but for my new project, it's using maven, in Netbeans I can't find a setting to set the project as a runnable jar, how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use either the assembly or shade maven plugins to configure creation of one uber-jar. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html